# Characteristic of a field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $\mathbb{F}_p$ be a field. Is it correct that the field extensions are $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, with $n \in \mathbb{N}$? And does the characteristic of every $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ equal $p$?

Comment: Those are the *finite* extensions. There are infinite ones too, like $\mathbf{F}_p(x)$ or $\overline{\mathbf{F}}_p$.

Comment: Yes, the characteristic is $p$: what happens if you add $1$ to itself $p$ times? (Recall that $\mathbb{F}_p \subseteq \mathbb{F}_{p^n})$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, all the **finite** field extensions are of the form $\mathbb F_{p^n}$ (up to isomorphism), and all these fields have characteristic $p$. Note that in general, the characteristic of a field is always equal to that of its prime subfield. Another way of looking at this: the only way you can have a morphism between two fields (remember that they are always *injective*) is if the two fields have the same characteristic; embedding is definitely a morphism.